# How to bind input change event for the entire fragment in Android?

Tags: android, events, android-fragments, input, fragment

Is there a way in Android to bind an input change event for the entire fragment like in the web we could do that for the entire form, when something changes by the user in input fields?

For example: Let's say I have an Fragment which contains different input views like TextField, CheckBox and e.t.c. I would like to bind an input change event for the all input fields and to be notified whether something has changed in on the UI by user or no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a way.

It's easy to define 'change' when speaking only about standard android views, but the concept is too abstract to be implemented like that, since 'change' may be different for custom components. Even TextView has 3 methods for when it's text is changed.

The thing you can do is to make your fragment implement `TextWatcher`, `OnCheckedChangeListener` (and other listeners for other form components) and set them in your views in `onViewCreated()` method.
In listeners trigger methods (`onAfterTextChanged`, `onChecked`, etc) you can call some updateUiState() method, that will check current state of your form and perform actions you want (it can check if all text fields are filled to enable submit button for example).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all components have listeners where you can handle events.

For example, checkbox:

```
checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sateliteCheckBox);

satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         if (isChecked){
                // perform logic
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: the question here is that I do not want to bind separate events for each View.